# How can I make VLC media player's Continue playback button to stay for longer?

Tags: vlc-media-player

I have made my Vlc player ask me if I want to continue playback from where I left it following this guide : https://www.vlchelp.com/restart-continue-playback-ask/

However, the button disappears in less than 3 seconds. How can I make that button stay a bit longer ?

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you can make it stay longer, but you are able to set it to always start from where you left off, without being asked. Here's how.:

1. Press Ctrl+p in VLC (Tools --> Preferences)
2. Look at the Interface settings, which is the default pane
3. Under the "Playlist and Instances" section, look for the "Continue playback?" question
4. Set the dropdown menu to "Always", and it will never ask you to start off where you 
    left off, but automatically start there
5. Hit the "Save" button and you're good to go

Rick